# Is it possible to monitor hidden file creation using auditctl? Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: home-directory, environment-variables

I want to monitor creation of hidden files in `/home/user`. Is it possible to create a rule which triggers when any hidden file created in `/home/user` folder using **auditctl**? (* or any other methods?)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to achieve that with auditd, but hidden files are simply files that start with a dot (.) symbol. As such, you can use the **fswatch** utility (provided by the fswatch package on Ubuntu) to monitor the directory for any file changes.

As an example, if you have a folder under /home/user/test/ and you run:

```
fswatch -t /home/user/test/
```

fswatch will now monitor that folder and upon file creations update events will occur, and you will be provided with the timestamp.

I have created the test_file4 file and received:

```
user@ubuntu:~/test$ fswatch -t ~/test
Tue 24 Oct 2023 02:51:41 PM GMT /home/user/test/test_file4
Tue 24 Oct 2023 02:51:42 PM GMT /home/user/test/test_file4
Tue 24 Oct 2023 02:51:42 PM GMT /home/user/test/test_file4
Tue 24 Oct 2023 02:51:42 PM GMT /home/user/test/test_file4
```

fswatch has more functions, check its man page to customize its output for your required pipeline.